# Exibir o QRCode na tela na aplicação web

Tags: java

Tenho esse código que gera o QRCode da biblioteca Zxing:

```java
private static byte[] getQRCodeImage(String text, int width, int height) throws WriterException, IOException {
  QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
  BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);

  ByteArrayOutputStream pngOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "PNG", pngOutputStream);
  byte[] pngData = pngOutputStream.toByteArray();
  return pngData;
}
```

Ele está retornando um array de bytes.

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web.

Como faço para exibir esse array como imagem na tela?

Comment: Sua aplicação é desenvolvida em Java e executada no navegador ou se trata de um web server?

Comment: JSF + PrimeFaces

Comment: Existem algumas informações relevantes [neste link](https://respostas.guj.com.br/22914-exibir-byte-no-pgraphicimage). Posteriormente escreverei uma resposta citando-os.